# Cannot remove app from Game Center group to delete app from ITC

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, game-center

I have a game with two versions: free and paid. The two versions use the same GC leaderboards via a group connection. I want to completely delete the free version from ITC. I have made the app "Developer removed from sale" and removed all In-App Purchases but now I need to remove the app from GC group to enable the "Delete" button in ITC.

According to Apple, I should go to the list of linked apps in the Game Center Management screen and click delete. Quote: "If the app is one of multiple apps listed in Apps in this Group, in the row for the app you want to remove from the group, click Delete" Attached is a screenshot of what I'm supposed to be seeing. However, I cannot actually see the "Delete" button and thus cannot figure out how to remove my app from the Game Center group.

I have tried to make a new version of the app I want to delete and then manage Game Center in hopes of something changing by putting the app in an edittable state but that did not help.

Attached is a screenshot of part of the GC Management screen that I am seeing and the one Apple says I should be seeing ITC.All help is appreciated.

My screenshot: http://tinypic.com/r/iz2rmu/8

Apple's Example: http://tinypic.com/r/zwfevl/8

Comment: Both screenshots are broken, fyi. It might be a referer issue; can you upload them to someplace like TinyPic instead?

Comment: @computerfreaker sorry for the issue. Images are updated.